# how to speed up ansible?

Tags: dns, ansible

We've implemented ansible recently. Somehow, we found it really slow, and wonder how to speed up.
So, I did some stracing, found /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/hosts related, then seemed to be the reverse DNS issue as follow:

```
18:32:13.961094 IP 192.168.22.2.44206 > 192.168.23.2.53: 12243+ PTR? xxx.xxx.29.115.in-addr.arpa. (45)
18:32:18.966199 IP 192.168.22.2.44206 > 192.168.23.2.53: 12243+ PTR? xxx.xxx.29.115.in-addr.arpa. (45)
18:32:18.967019 IP 192.168.23.2.53 > 192.168.22.2.44206: 12243 NXDomain* 0/0/0 (45)
18:32:18.967986 IP 192.168.22.2.44057 > 192.168.23.2.53: 19913+ PTR? xxx.xxx.29.115.in-addr.arpa. (45)
18:32:23.973096 IP 192.168.22.2.44057 > 192.168.23.2.53: 19913+ PTR? xxx.xxx.29.115.in-addr.arpa. (45)
18:32:23.976649 IP 192.168.23.2.53 > 192.168.22.2.44057: 19913 NXDomain* 0/0/0 (45)

18:32:23.977230 IP 192.168.22.2.44997 > 192.168.23.2.53: 8795+ PTR? xxx.xxx.29.115.in-addr.arpa. (45)
18:32:28.982280 IP 192.168.22.2.44997 > 192.168.23.2.53: 8795+ PTR? xxx.xxx.29.115.in-addr.arpa. (45)
18:32:28.982980 IP 192.168.23.2.53 > 192.168.22.2.44997: 8795 NXDomain* 0/0/0 (45)
18:32:28.983550 IP 192.168.22.2.38603 > 192.168.23.2.53: 41907+ PTR? xxx.xxx.29.115.in-addr.arpa. (45)
18:32:33.988665 IP 192.168.22.2.38603 > 192.168.23.2.53: 41907+ PTR? xxx.xxx.29.115.in-addr.arpa. (45)
18:32:33.989414 IP 192.168.23.2.53 > 192.168.22.2.38603: 41907 NXDomain* 0/0/0 (45)
```

As you see, it cost 20s to do the PTR? query per node.(real node IP is replaced by xxx.xxx).
So, why ansible had to do the reverse DNS query? And can we just simple disable it ? How ?

BTW, FYI, we've changed the default "ControlPersist=30s" longer within ansible.cfg and it really helps a lot afterwards. But the reverse DNS query delay while initiating the connection is absolutely unacceptable, too.

Comment: and FYI, make your own /etc/hosts with the node recoder is an option. But, come on, imaging hundreds and tons of nodes !!!

Comment: kiiwii: some input is lacking to help diagnose this. I've just made a quick test, I see no PTR query firing. Can you show a minimal playbook + inventory where this happens ?

Comment: @leucos Just as simple as executing "ansible db2 -a "id", and db2 defined under group [dbs] as "db2 ansible_ssh_host=115.29.xxx.xxx"

Comment: You should probably be looking at your ssh configuration for the reverse lookups, not the Ansible config. Also, if you use RFC1918 IP space (192.168.x.x, in this case) heavily, do consider setting up your own reverse servers for it instead of hitting the global blackhole servers.

Comment: Still can't reproduce. Though about PTR resolution coming from ssh but it doesn't fire any. Tried ssh, paramiko, never saw a PTR req. Your best chance might be to 'strace -f' this. Can you try that ? Ansible version BTW ?

Comment: yeah, @ leucos, Debian 8, ansible ver 1.7.2+dfsg-2, and I did a further 'strace -f', then @CalleDybedahl, you're right ! It's raw "ssh" command involved. Afterwards comes the funny thing, tcpdump captures PTR queries while running "ssh 115.29.xxx.xxx", However, "ssh 104.236.xxx.xxx" produces no PTR query. I'm sure these IPs are not configured in /etc/hosts nor ssh config. So far so good, a new clue, great :D. But dose it help?

Comment: Oh !!! might found it when ssh -vvv, stuck with "debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @leucos and @CalleDybedahl, this issue finally leads to ssh gssapi authentication method. After appending "GSSAPIAuthentication=no" to ssh_args within ansible.cfg, there is no PTR query any more.
FYI, we make it in ~/.ssh/config, too, for no GSSAPI Authentication implemented in our environment at all.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to speed up Ansible, here are my observations.

The order in which SSH tries authentication matters a lot. Generally with Ansible, we use Public Key Authentication. 
So after adding the **PreferredAuthentications** entry in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` increased the speed by almost 17 times.

> ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60m -o **PreferredAuthentications=publickey**

Below are the results.

```
[admin@SON-DOCM ~]$ time ansible -m ping 2405:200:xxx:xxxx::6:40
2405:200:xxx:xxxx::6:40 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}

real    0m31.897s
user    0m1.307s
sys     0m0.248s
[admin@SON-DOCM ~]$ vi /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[admin@SON-DOCM ~]$ time ansible -m ping 2405:200:xxx:xxxx::6:40
2405:200:xxx:xxxx::6:40 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}

real    0m1.882s
user    0m0.757s
sys     0m0.172s
```